# Andengine VS Unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, andengine, game-engine

I am new to Game Development.
I have java background and want to develop an android game as final assignment for android course.
(I don't have much time to develop)

I search around and see AndEngine is a good engine for android game development.
But there is a famous game engine, the Unity 3D which is more interesting to me.

Among these two engine, what should I prefer?

some of criteria

- I have background in Java
- I have only one month to develop
- My game will be 2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would recommend unity. Reason:

1. You only have 1 month, which is not long enough for developing games. While unity is designed to make game developing as easy as possible. Even non-programmers can make games using it because it minimizes scripting (still has to learn basic programming though).
2. You have background in Java. Unity gives you option to develop your game in Javascript, C#, and Boo. I don't quite understand about Boo but C# should be quite similar to Java, therefore you should be able to pick it up quickly.
3. You are new to Game Development. Unity really really makes it easier for you to develop games. I was so stunned when I started learning Unity (my background: I had developed games without using engine at all) because there are a ton of functionality that you just have to write in 1 line, but actually you have to write more than 100 lines if you do it manually without game engine.
4. In the recent updates, Unity has fully supported 2D games (eventhough its name is still Unity3d), so you don't have to worry about its 3D engine. It has many built in components for 2D games, so just use them.

However I think Unity has 1 downfall, especially for mobile games. The minimum size of your installer (.apk in android) is about 7 MB, which is quite big if you compare it to game engines like cocos2d or andengine.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried Unity, so I cannot answer for that.

But I find that [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) is better documented than AndEngine (at least when I tried them last time).

Comment: Thank Tomas, I will explore it

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unity uses 2 or 3 languages main being C# and javascript
If you are good at C++ and Java .. I would recommend you either (http://www.cocos2d-x.org) which is an open source C++ based game engine

or try (libgdx) which is a java based game engine!